# Sudden traceroute time jump between ISP and requested server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, isp, traceroute

I've been having trouble these past few months with certain websites timing out or acting really slow, so I decided to do some traceroute testing. One particular website I try to access called "vp.crossmark.com" is very bad about its loading time. Following is the tracert output for the URL above:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]>tracert vp.crossmark.com

Tracing route to vp.crossmark.com [64.128.22.182]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    12 ms     9 ms     4 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *      324 ms    10 ms  208-180-188-197.suddenlink.net [208.180.188.197]

  4     *       56 ms    55 ms  173-219-224-142.suddenlink.net [173.219.224.142]

  5     *      364 ms   237 ms  173-219-227-44.suddenlink.net [173.219.227.44]
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10    36 ms    37 ms    40 ms  dal1-ar1-ae21-0.us.twtelecom.net [66.192.243.70]

 11     *        *       43 ms  50.58.193.110
 12     *        *       42 ms  test-vp.crossmark.com [64.128.22.182]

Trace complete.
```

Here's another for comparision:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]> tracert vp.crossmark.com

Tracing route to vp.crossmark.com [64.128.22.182]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  router.asus.com [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *       16 ms  208-180-188-197.suddenlink.net [208.180.188.197]

  4     *        *       99 ms  173-219-224-142.suddenlink.net [173.219.224.142]

  5   256 ms   243 ms     *     173-219-227-44.suddenlink.net [173.219.227.44]
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *       18 ms  ae-1-60.edge5.Dallas3.Level3.net [4.69.145.14]
  9    21 ms    20 ms    23 ms  dal2-pr1-ae1-0.us.twtelecom.net [64.128.212.65]

 10    42 ms    37 ms    38 ms  dal1-ar1-ae21-0.us.twtelecom.net [66.192.243.70]

 11    42 ms    41 ms    43 ms  50.58.193.110
 12   121 ms     *       42 ms  test-vp.crossmark.com [64.128.22.182]

Trace complete.
```

I noticed that the ping time between the suddenlink servers and the servers that connect to crossmark takes a massive jump into the 200-400 range. I've repeated this a few times and I constantly find massive jumps in ping time or even several timeouts at the same point between networks.

I'm wondering if this is a sign of connectivity issues between my ISP and the servers I am requesting. This website isn't the only one doing this by the way, but most larger sites like google, youtube, or wikipedia make the jump without sudden ping time increase.

Comment: Just tried a tracert, didn't do it for me, also came with a diff URL but the same ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly and obviously not since the times to points past that are just fine. If this were a problem with a slow router or link, all points past it would show a delay as traffic passes through that slow point. All you have here is a router that's not a very good responder.

Comment: This isn't unusual, by the way. Modern Internet core routers are heavily optimized to be efficient forwarders, the most efficient we can possibly make them. Sending ICMP responses takes a much slower path that typically requires passing through a CPU that gives a much higher priority to other tasks like updating the forwarding table.